# I need to add library to my project with javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea, text-editor, lib

I want to add [this library](https://github.com/komagata/textarea-markdown) to my local project, I don't want to install npm.
Can I just add the library to my project manually? if yes **how?**.
I have small experience with javascript, I just want to do a simple project.

Comment: Why don't you want to install npm?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is download the js file from the `lib` https://github.com/komagata/textarea-markdown/tree/master/lib directory and include it as a script take in your project: `<script src="path/to/js.js"></script>`

Comment: I try it, didn't work

Comment: @MoonXApp Are you getting any console errors. I see that in `package.json` 2 dependencies are required: "dependencies": {
    "markdown-it": "^8.4.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },

Comment: Yes,  ReferenceError: exports is not defined, so I must download the dependencies or what?

Comment: Yes you need to go fetch the dependencies too. For urls, go to npmjs.org and search for those packages. Alternatively, install npm in your machine or a VM and download the files and then copy paste them to your project

Comment: Thanks, I finally found the `js` file I want it.